# CSS Shape over navigation tab

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element, clip-path

I want to generate a design like below. A "new" on the top of plans tab. The properties that i have used works well with chrome and mozilla but breaks down in Edge.

[image]

Below is the styles i applied to get the job done in chrome:

```
a.subnav__items{
padding-left: 15px !important;
 &::after {
    content:"NEW";
    display: block; 
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:8px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#D61800;

     @supports ( clip-path:polygon(0 0) ) or ( -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0) ){                        
        transform: rotate(-50deg);           
        width:40px; 
        top: 6px;
        left: -11px;        
        clip-path:polygon(60% -65%,100% 87%,0 91%,7% 74%);
        -webkit-clip-path:polygon(60% -65%,100% 87%,0 91%,7% 74%);           
     }

 }
```

}

The markup for the style is this:

```
    <div class="subnav">

  <div  *ngFor="let item of subHeaders;let i=index;">
    <a   [ngClass]="{subnav__items: item.label=='plans' && i==4}" href="#" >{{item.label}}
    </a>
  </div>


</div>
```

The same style yield a different result in ME. Clip-path property doesn't seem to work for Edge as it is not yet supported.

[image]

Is there any better way to achieve it? I'm stuck at this issue for a while now.

Comment: An image might work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow:hidden` for the navigation items maybe?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was supposed to do. That was probably the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` in parent tag of `new` tag.

Comment: Not all heroes wear cap. Thanks rohit verma it worked. Such a simple solution i couldn't come across. It doesn't even need a clip path.